# Executing javascript in loaded page

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-tools

My users recently told me that default page loads much slower than before.
I think its because Maps is loaded immediately as the page loads.
Is there a way to delay it until the click here button clicked?

---

Based on the suggestions I received from the answers so far, I decided to call the map from an external URL.
But Javascript on loaded page is not executed.
Hoe can I fix this?

Thanks!

This is how I call the external page.

```
$(function() {

    // if the function argument is given to overlay,
    // it is assumed to be the onBeforeLoad event listener
    $("a[rel]").overlay({

        mask: 'darkred',
        effect: 'apple',

        onBeforeLoad: function() {

            // grab wrapper element inside content
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");

            // load the page specified in the trigger
            wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        }

    });
});
<!-- external page is given in the href attribute (as it should be) -->
<a href="default.cs.asp?Process=ViewCheckinMap" rel="#overlay" style="text-decoration:none">
  <!-- remember that you can use any element inside the trigger -->
  <button type="button">Show external page in overlay</button>
</a>
```

This is what is not executed.

```
<script>
      function initialize() {
        var data = <%=Data%>;
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(48.404840395764175, 2.6845264434814453);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++) {
          var location = data.users[i];
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude,
              location.longitude);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'click', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regarding your changed question:

remove `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'click', initialize);`

change `wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));` to:

```
wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"), function(){initialize();});
```

this should initialize your map, right after loading the external javascript.

not tested :(

Comment: Error: initialize is not defined.

Comment: than you have an error in the rest of your javascript. your top js-code maybe doesnt show the beginning of your script. the ending `});` suggests that.

your function `initialize` should be defined before loading the content.

Comment: What if I simply loaded it from another page as agriboz suggested above. Why do you think that is not working?

Comment: you could do it with an external site, but you started with the onpage version, so i suggest to go with it.

Comment: i cannot see the maps-js on that page. specially the `initialize()`-function.

Comment: so, this isnt what your question was for. :-( you should follow agriboz intend.

Comment: Your last suggestion worked! Just one final question, if I want to use Overlay feature to load other external pages without triggering initialize function. Do you think that I should add an if statement in that overlay function?

Comment: make a special call `$("a[rel=gmap]").overlay({` and set rel on the link to "gmap". call other overlays with different functions.

Answer (score 1):

That means you an need external page loaded with ajax.

To do that make a new html page. And name it map.html. in *map.html* page just put your google map code.

for your default page `<a href="map.htm" rel="#overlay">Click here to open the map</a>`.

After that your map will be loaded in .*contentWrap* div that using ajax method.

```
<!-- overlayed element -->
 <div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay">
  <!-- the external content is loaded inside this tag (map.html) -->
  <div class="contentWrap"></div>
 </div>
```

Css for the *.contentWrap*

```
/* container for external content. uses vertical scrollbar, if needed */
div.contentWrap {
height: 400px; // it is the same height of the #map div
overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: this didnt work. main page doesnt load the map from the new page. No errors, any idea why?

Comment: do you have this `<div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay">
  <!-- the external content is loaded inside this tag (map.html) -->
  <div class="contentWrap"></div>
 </div>` in your default page

Comment: You are missing one thing
`<a href="map.htm" rel="#overlay">Click here to open the map</a>` you have to use this 
not `<a rel="#map">Click here to open the map</a>`

Comment: No sorry page wasnt uploaded properly try it again, its there.

Comment: make sure that your overlay.css and your google map script are defined.

Comment: if I put a text in that other page (even in map div), it loads but the map doesnt load.